# How can I avoid that people use other characters than the ones that I support in a text box?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xna, monogame

I only want to support the following ascii characters in my iOS/Android application:

```
 <!--
CharacterRegions control what letters are available in the font. Every
character from Start to End will be built and made available for drawing. The
default range is from 32, (ASCII space), to 126, ('~'), covering the basic Latin
character set. The characters are ordered according to the Unicode standard.
See the documentation for more information.
-->
<CharacterRegions>
  <CharacterRegion>
  <Start>&#32;</Start>
  <End>&#512;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
  <CharacterRegion>
  <!-- Apostrophe 8217 -->
  <Start>&#8216;</Start>
  <End>&#8222;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
  <CharacterRegion>
  <!-- Currency symbols -->
  <Start>&#8352;</Start>
  <End>&#8378;</End>
  </CharacterRegion>
</CharacterRegions>
```

Is it possible to disable all other ascii characters somehow in my application so that people can only choose the supported characters on their soft keyboard in my application?

I only want to support English, Spanish, Italian, French, German and Portuguese characters, and some special characters like currency symbols. I don't want that someone can use asian characters.

How can I avoid that people use other characters than the ones that I support in a text box?

Is it possible to disable certain soft keyboard buttons so a player can not use them or is it always necessary that I check the text box characters if they are supported after a player has entered them with the soft keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is possible.  You just need a TextWatcher.

```
textField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    // Check to make sure the new text entered 
    // matches your requirements, otherwise, 
    // remove it from the text field.

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```